# Изображение в модальном окне HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста - хочу реализовать модальное окно с открытием увеличенного изображения. Почему-то при открытие второго и последующих окон всегда открывается изображение из первого.

```css
/* Базовые стили слоя затемнения и модального окна  */

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  /* фон затемнения */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  position: fixed;
  /* фиксированное поцизионирование */
  cursor: default;
  /* тип курсара */
}


/* активируем слой затемнения */

.overlay:target {
  display: block;
}


/* стили модального окна */

.popup {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 20;
  margin: 0;
  width: 85%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  /* фиксированное позиционирование, окно стабильно при прокрутке */
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  background: #fefefe;
  /* скругление углов */
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  /* внешняя тень */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}


/* активируем модальный блок */

.overlay:target+.popup {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 20%;
}


/* формируем кнопку закрытия */

.close {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -ms-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .8s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .8s;
  -o-transition: all ease .8s;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}

.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/* изображения внутри окна */

.popup img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* миниатюры слева/справа */

.pic-left,
.pic-right {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.pic-left {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 0;
}

.pic-right {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}


/* элементы м-медиа, фреймы */

.popup embed,
.popup iframe {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup h2 {
  /* заголовок 2 */
  margin: 0;
  color: #008000;
  padding: 5px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #adadad;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}


/* параграфы */

.popup p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="home_list">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#win5"><img title="" src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <!-- Модальное окно №5 -->
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win5"></a>
        <div class="popup">
          <img class="is-image" src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg" alt="" />
          <a class="close" title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#win5"><img title="" src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <!-- Модальное окно №5 -->
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win6"></a>
        <div class="popup">
          <img class="is-image" src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16.jpg" alt="" />
          <a class="close" title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Вот ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgOWZw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот в этой строчке `<a href="#win5"><img title="" src="https://bipbap.ru`
замените `#win5` на `#win6`, начиная со второго фото, для следующих фото так же на увеличение.

Comment: @Crowl Попробуйте в стилях прописать .is-image{width:320px;} 320 px это разрешение, с ним играйтесь